# Visual Studio 2017 prefix file nesting

Tags: asp.net-core, nested, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to group files with same suffix but with variant prefix.

Example:

```
-hero.model.ts
    -power.hero.model.ts
    -weapon.hero.model.ts
        -bullet.weapon.hero.model.ts
```

This guide (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/07/file-nesting-in-solution-explorer/) says:

> fileSuffixToExtension: Use this type of rule to make file-vsdoc.js nest under file.js

or

> pathSegment: Use this type of rule to make jquery.min.js nest under jquery.js

I'm looking for the same thing but with prefix instead of suffix.
I'm using VS2017 with a .Net Core 2.1 project.

Comment: Why not make it easy on yourself and abide by the rules you get out of the box: `hero.model.power.ts` and `hero.model.weapon.ts` ?

Comment: @Sigge because it doesn't fit the namming convention imo. If I follow your suggestion, the files should be nammed like this: `hero.model.weapon.ts`. But I'm on an Angular project, and the files names should end with the class' type (model.ts in my case but it can be heroes.service.ts for services' classes). We can read the name like "I'm the weapon of the heros wich is a model type".

Comment: I understand that your intended naming convention is more logical. Have you tried playing around with the `allExtensions` provider? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer#the-allextensions-provider

Comment: Yes I've tried but I cannot find any rule matching my needs.

Comment: I am looking for the same sort of thing but for dependency injection in regards to Interface and class. `IBlahRepository.cs` under `BlahRepository.cs` I don't currently see a way to accommodate for the prefixes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to nest interfaces using File Nesting in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717419/how-to-nest-interfaces-using-file-nesting-in-asp-net-core)