# How to nest interfaces using File Nesting in ASP.Net Core

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I want to use Microsoft's custom file nesting option in Visual Studio to nest implementation class files with their "parent" interfaces, so in this example, I would like `ReportRepository.cs` to appear nested under `IReportRepository.cs` in the solution explorer. The same should be for all repositories.

[image: Files in Solution Explorer]

I have created the `.filenesting.json` file in the root of the solution, but I have no idea how to use it and [documentation is very sparse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2019).

Does anyone know how I can achieve this in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901094/visual-studio-2017-prefix-file-nesting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can gather it is not possible to group by prefixes. You can only group by extensions or suffixes, or entire file names.

This means you can't define a rule for this. However there are 2 options:

- Define a rule for each file
- Change your naming scheme

## Defining a rule for each file

To define a rule for each file you would use the `fileToFile` provider.
This would look like so:

```
{
  "help": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866610",
  "root": true,

  "dependentFileProviders": {
    "add": {
      "fileToFile": {
        "add": {
          "IInvestigationRepository.cs": [ // Parent file
            "InvestigationRepository.cs"   // Nested file
          ],
          "IReporterRepository.cs": [ // Parent file
            "ReporterRepository.cs"   // Nested file
          ]
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Using a different naming scheme

Alternatively, if the first option is not to your liking, you could use a different naming scheme for your files, and let the classes keep their old names.

Then you could use the `fileSuffixToExtension` provider like such:

```
{
  "help": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866610",
  "root": true,

  "dependentFileProviders": {
    "add": {
      "pathSegment": {
        "add": {
          ".DefaultImplementation.cs": [
            ".cs"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would map

- `IInvestigationRepository.DefaultImplementation.cs`to `IInvestigationRepository.cs`,
- `IReporterRepository.DefaultImplementation.cs`to `IReporterRepository.cs`

and so on.

This would also make the purpose of your files clearer, as just having the same name doesn't tell you what it's doing with the Interface, just that is has something to do with it.

If you don't want to use a notation with `.` and would prefer to use `-`, you can do that by replacing `"pathSegment"` with `"fileSuffixToExtension"`, and replacing `".DefaultImplementation.cs"` with `"-DefaultImplementation.cs"`

Comment: Note for others: this does not work with .NET Standard 2.0 projects. See the big note at the top of Microsofts docs on this feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2019 "The feature is currently only supported for ASP.NET Core projects." Was trying every which way to get this to work in .NET Standard... then finally read the top part...

Comment: fileToFile works the opposite, the item in the array is the parent (counter-intuitive, imo, and a conceptual bug)
see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022#the-filetofile-provider

Comment: is there a possibility to nest files below filename.cs where naming convention is
filename.cs
filename.somethingelse.cs
filename.anotherthins.cs

Comment: For those looking/waiting for this feature for non-ASP.Net projects, this can be enabled by adding the `PorjectCapability` within your .csproj file. See DrewNoakes comment inhttps://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/7939. Hopefully this will be formally solved and supported soon.  I miss having the explicit control of nesting like I had with the NestIn extension in VS2019/.NetFramework projects, but renaming my contract interface filenames is an acceptable work-around.

Answer (score 6):

We use the following pattern in our .csproj files to auto nest concretes with their interfaces (if they reside in the same directory).

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="**\*.cs">
        <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy(I%(Filename).cs))</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

I know that the question was to use the custom nesting options in Visual Studio; however, until Microsoft adds prefix functionality, this method does the trick.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed a useful alternative!